# Validation errors in microsoft data migration assistant

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-migration

I am using microsoft data migration assistant to migrate my SQL server database into Azure SQL server database. When I fill out the servername, authentication type, user name and password and select "Encrypt connection" and "Trust server certificate" I am getting the following error message:

> There are validation errors in the source server. Please fix the
>   issues and go to the next step

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to select source. Source means our local SQL server database. You can connect to the source by using server name and authentication type. Once you connect you can select the database that you want to migrate. Then you should select the target. Target is your azure SQL server database. understand the difference and give proper credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the "Trust Server Certificate" checkbox.

Comment: Have you tried running the assessment to see if there are items preventing the migration?

Comment: What it means "Encrypt connection" and "Trust server certificate" for Data Migration Assistance? Is something optional or it depends on our database configuration?